# php-maven repository is not available?

Tags: php, maven, zend-framework

I am trying to build up project for php using php-maven using zend framework which has embedded jetty server.

Looked at various option on web but did not find anything useful.

With the lot of information available on web I tried configured php-maven but seems like php-maven (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release, http://repos.php-maven.org/release) repo is down. Can anyone provide any further information on this? Is php-maven out of development?

I followed few links but did not get anything out of it:
../php-zend-5min.html

I am looking for if there are any other way through which I can mavenized my php web project and run through embedded jetty? Including my php-unit tests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if the maven way is the right for php to go with. May phing.info might be a better alternative? Apart from that the web site looks like not maintained any more...may be you can write the author a email and see it's reaction.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise looked at phing it looks good, the advantage of maven is to have embedded jetty not sure if phing can provide.. as it is ant like.